# Apache: Cannot create a file in /var/www/html/siteroot

Tags: apache2, php7

So I was executing some PHP code in XAMPP to create a new file for each user and write some contents to it.
It worked in XAMPP on Windows, but when I copied it over to Ubuntu, it doesnt work.
The PHP page cannot create a new file. If the file already exists, it can detect it as it exists, can read the contents, but cannot open it in append mode.
What can I do?
How do I add permissions for the apache2 user so that it can write at the location of the site in /var/www/html/siteroot   ?

Comment: `sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html`, then add yourself to the group `sudo gpasswd -a username www-data`

Comment: And make permissions `775` with `sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this do the following:

1. Change `group ownership` of `/var/www/html`:

   ```
   sudo chgrp -R www-data /var/www/html
   ```
2. Add yourself to the `apache group`:

   ```
   sudo gpasswd -a username www-data
   ```
3. Modify the file permissions of `/var/www/html`:

   ```
   sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/html
   ```

Comment: Sure, it worked. Thanks. However, it only works for file_put_contents(); and not for fopen($path,'w');

Comment: In church, mean while can I see the path your trying to access?

Comment: Hi back home, can I see the path your trying to access?